# How to position image to the right of personal details when using currvita?

Tags: graphics, currvita

How to position the image to the right of personal details instead of below?

[image]

Here is the code to produce the CV above.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned, NoDate]{currvita}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE}

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{30.12.2000}

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[2]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=1 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1em}\parbox{0.84\textwidth}{#2}

\vspace{0.5em}}

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}}

%%%%

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}


%%%% NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Random Name}}\vspace{1.5em}

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal details}\vspace{0.5em}

\NewEntry{Born}{Yes}
\NewEntry{Address}{In the wilds}
\NewEntry{Email}{me@my-email-domain.com}
\NewEntry{website}{http://www.my-awsome-website.com}
\NewEntry{Phone}{0123456789}


%%%% THIS IMAGE TO THE RIGHT OF NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION

\begin{figure}[H]
\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=30mm]{unknown-person.jpg}
\end{figure}

\vspace{1em}


%%%% WORK EXPERIENCE

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work experience}\vspace{1em}

\pagebreak[2]
\NewEntry{01.01.2015\,--02.01.2015}{\mbox{Impressive title here,} \mbox{\textsc{Fortune 500 company}}}

\Description{%
\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont
\textit{Responsibilities:} Read the newspapers. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. And read the newspapers.
}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `minipage`s

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned, NoDate]{currvita}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE}

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{30.12.2000}

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[2]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=1 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1em}\parbox{0.84\textwidth}{#2}

\vspace{0.5em}}

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}}

%%%%

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}


%%%% NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Random Name}}\vspace{1.5em}

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal details}\vspace{0.5em}

\medskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\NewEntry{Born}{Yes}
\NewEntry{Address}{In the wilds}
\NewEntry{Email}{me@my-email-domain.com}
\NewEntry{website}{http://www.my-awsome-website.com}
\NewEntry{Phone}{0123456789}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \raggedleft
  \includegraphics[height=30mm]{photo}
\end{minipage}


%%%% THIS IMAGE TO THE RIGHT OF NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%% or use this
%\noindent\raisebox{10mm}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\includegraphics[height=30mm]{photo}}}

\vspace{1em}


%%%% WORK EXPERIENCE

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work experience}\vspace{1em}

\pagebreak[2]
\NewEntry{01.01.2015\,--02.01.2015}{\mbox{Impressive title here,} \mbox{\textsc{Fortune 500 company}}}

\Description{%
\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont
\textit{Responsibilities:} Read the newspapers. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. And read the newspapers.
}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]